# Ionic devapp just searching

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm having a problem with the Ionic DevApp application .. I use the "ionic serve -c" command it opens in the browser, but on my device it is just looking for .. "Listening for apps on your network". It is not appearing on my device, however I have already tested on 2 other devices, and in them appears the project in the list. I even formatted my Android device, but still can not find the project. Anyone have any idea what it can be? Why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: I do not know exactly what solved, I gave up because it did not work, I think going back to the version of ionic I used before has improved. ionic 3 Ionic Cli 4.3.1.
I'm not sure, but I really think it has something to do with the versions of DevApp and Ionic

Answer (score 0):

How to run the ionic app using devapp:

1. Navigate to the Ionic Project folder via cmd line.
2. *Disable your Firewall* - Enabled Firewall  is what causes the buffering problem.
3. Run cmd `ionic serve --devapp`
4. Search for the app in the devapp on your android phone which is connected to the same wifi network like Hotspot or via Home Wifi Router.